# How to send file along with other data in jsonobject in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using c# webapi as server side code in which communication between client android and webapi will happen. But am trying to send data from android to server am sending in jsonobject format. But my doubt is how to send some files saved in my sqlite database to server along with some data, am saving path of the file in sqlite database. I have tried multipart request in which i can send file and data separately but i need to send that in jsonobject is it possible to do so, Now let me post what i have tried so far:

This is my json:

`{"Remarks":"test","UserID":193,"FindingsAtSite":"nothing","CheckInDate":"2017-02-01 12:00:00","CheckOutDate":"2017-02-01 12:00:00","VisitStatusID":1,"CreatedBy":192,"CreatedDateTime":"2017-02-01 12:00:00","Claim":{"TransportMode":1,"Date":"2017-02-01 12:00:00","FromLocation":"test","ToLocation":"re","Ticket":123.2,"Conveyance":123.5,"Lodge":234.0,"Meals":23},"File":"/sd/0/ed.txt"}`

how to send file along with this jsonobject?

file part is not mandatory; sometimes file may not be available.

Comment: You can not send File with json , But you can send File object  along  with json data using multipart.

Comment: can you share some code snippet

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: Of course you can send files wrapped in your json text.  Encode the bytes of the file in a base64 string. Then just add as parameter `, "filecontent1:" + base64String`.

Comment: can you please elaborate